# PC turned off durring upgrade to 15.10. Now only have terminal page. What can I do

Tags: system-installation

PC got turned off during the upgrade to 15.10. Now I only have a terminal screen. What can I do. Do I have to load from CD and lose all my files ?

Comment: You could use a live CD/USB to boot into your system, connect an external HDD and backup your files and do a new install then afterwards.

Comment: How do I get a live USB to boot from?  Will this delete everything on hard drive? Or just allow me to boot u ubuntu so I can retrieve files?  Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you mean by just a terminal .. if its the full terminal you can try "startx" to try to start xwindows. This is all I can think of with the information given. I may be wrong ... that might not be the command ... its been a while since I have had to start it manually. You could also try Ctrl+Alt+F7 to see if you may be in TTY1 instead of TTY7 which is usually the GUI

Comment: I wasnt able to reply to the comment above because I don't have the rep yet but ... if you go to [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) it will explain how to create a Ubuntu bootable USB. Just choose the "try" option not the install and you should be able to access your files  and save them if you need to start from scratch. The link is to create one on a Windows PC. hope this helps

Comment: When the computer is on it says it is running on tty1. How do I change it to tty7. I tried Ctrl+apt+f7 but the screen just goes blank with a flashing text line.

Comment: Also the startx worked and I can have access to files to save. Thanks for everything.

Comment: sounds like xwindows isn't running .. did you try startx command? lol and I'm assuming that the apt was a misprint and you meant Alt :D lol oops .. you answered my question as I was typing it :D